# how to let Jupiter automatically display all the functions in an object in a dropdown menu?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I was watching a YouTube video about python. He is using Jupiter notebook. He can select a pandas function of an object from a dropdown list (image below). It's hard to memorize all these function. I don't have this feature in my Jupyter notebook? How to enable this feature? Can anyone help.
Thank you!!!

[click to show the screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qAvE.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can activate autocomplete using `TAB` or `SHIFT + TAB`

Or, you can install this plugin [Hinterland](https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nbextensions/hinterland/README.html) that adds autocomplete while typing.